# Building corpus in Quanteda while keeping track of the ID

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I have a dataset in which I have multiple texts per user. I want to build a corpus of all those documents with Quanteda but without losing the ability to link back the different texts to the corresponding user.

I will give you a sample code to help you understand a little bit more where I am failing.

```
df <- data.frame('ID'=c(1,1,2), 'Text'=c('I ate apple', "I don't like fruits", "I swim in the dark"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_corpus <- corpus(df$Text, docnames =df$ID)
corpus_DFM <- dfm(df_corpus, tolower = TRUE, stem = FALSE)
print(corpus_DFM)
```

This results in

```
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 10 features (60.0% sparse).
3 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
     features
docs  i ate apple don't like fruits swim in the dark
  1   1   1     1     0    0      0    0  0   0    0
  1.1 1   0     0     1    1      1    0  0   0    0
  2   1   0     0     0    0      0    1  1   1    1
>
```

But I would like to obtain in dataframe that looks like this in my Document-feature matrix

```
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 10 features (60.0% sparse).
3 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    id  i ate apple don't like fruits swim in the dark
  text1 1   1   1     1     0    0      0    0  0   0    0
  text2 1   1   0     0     1    1      1    0  0   0    0
  text3 2   1   0     0     0    0      0    1  1   1    1
>
```

Is there a way to automatize this process using Quanteda.
I would like to modify the the docs column of the dfm object but I do not know how to have access to it.

Any help would be welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are specifying the docnames as "ID", but document names have to be unique.  This is why the corpus constructor function assigns 1, 1.1, 2 to your docnames based on the non-unique ID.

Solution?  Let `corpus()` assign the docnames, and keep `ID` as a docvar (document variable).  Easiest to do this by inputting the data.frame to `corpus()`, which calls the data.frame method than the character method for `corpus()`.  (See ?corpus.)

Change your code to be:

```
> df_corpus <- corpus(df, text_field =  "Text")
> corpus_DFM <- dfm(df_corpus, tolower = TRUE, stem = FALSE)
> print(corpus_DFM)
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 10 features (60.0% sparse).
3 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
       features
docs    i ate apple don't like fruits swim in the dark
  text1 1   1     1     0    0      0    0  0   0    0
  text2 1   0     0     1    1      1    0  0   0    0
  text3 1   0     0     0    0      0    1  1   1    1
> 
> docvars(corpus_DFM, "ID")
[1] 1 1 2
```

This enables you to easily recombine your dfm by user, if you want:

```
> dfm_group(corpus_DFM, groups = "ID")
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 10 features (45.0% sparse).
2 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
    features
docs i ate apple don't like fruits swim in the dark
   1 2   1     1     1    1      1    0  0   0    0
   2 1   0     0     0    0      0    1  1   1    1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an interesting solution that will actually help a lot when it comes to supervised learning afterwards.